# GT-I9100G screen replacement

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, screen, hardware

I have a GT-I9100G and the screen went bad, I'd like to replace it but all the screen replacements on amazon are for the GT-I9100 version. They look the same but I am still not sure if this will work with my GT-19100G? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the same screen type as the I9100, the main difference is the processor.

## [Samsung Galaxy S2 GT-I9100 vs. GT-I9100G Comparison Guide](http://people-caring.com/samsung-galaxy-s2-gt-i9100-vs-gt-i9100g-comparison-guide/)

> Basically both the I9100 and I9100G have the identical features as claimed by Samsung but the only thing that differentiate both is the processor and GPU that the unit run. I9100 run on 1.2GHz ARM CortexA9 Exynos 4210and ARM Mali-400 GPU while I9100G uses Texas Instruments OMAP4430 CPU and PowerVR SGX540 GPU.